# Truncated pyramid in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

Consider a truncated pyramid bounded by two rectangles:

```
Rectangle[{-100, -125}, {100, 125}]
Rectangle[{-200, -250}, {200, 250}]
```

The first rectangle is located at z = -1948 and the other one is at z = 2578.

Is it possible to plot this figure using `Graphics3D`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arbitrarily assuming two heights:

```
h1 = 0;
h2 = 100;


pts = {{-200, -250, h1}, {-200, 250, h1}, {200, 250, h1}, {200, -250, 
    h1},
   {-100, -150, h2}, {-100, 150, h2}, {100, 150, h2}, {100, -150, h2}
   };
polyh = ConvexHullRegion[pts]

Graphics3D[{polyh
  }
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 , Axes -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To have non-colored sides use `Glow` and adjust `Opacity` as desired:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Glow[White]
  , Opacity[0.5]
  , polyh
  }
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 , Axes -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Using `Region` functionality:

```
p1 = Pyramid[{{-200, -250, h1}, {-200, 250, h1}, {200, 250, 
    h1}, {200, -250, h1}, {0, 0, 200}}]

RegionQ /@ {p1, Cuboid[{-200, -250, h1}, {200, 250, h2}]}
```

> {True, True}

```
Region[Style[
  RegionIntersection[p1, Cuboid[{-200, -250, h1}, {200, 250, h2}]], 
  Darker@Cyan]
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to not fill the sides of this figure with colors?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Please see update.

Comment: Thanks again. Which version of Mathematica you are using? In my version of Mathematica (12.1), ConvexHullRegion is not defined.

Comment: "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" on Win7-x64.